# Flutter - Error - type '(String, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, widget

I have an issue with a function. It was working fine before. But now, it is not. I am getting this error message.

type '(String, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

I am trying to get the extension of a file. Then, depending of the extension, I want to display an icon (pdf) or a small preview of a picture if the extension is jpeg or jpg.

Thank you

```
SizedBox(
                        height: 113, width: 113,
                        child: getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(
                            newFilesAdded[index])),
```

```
containerContentCard(String origin, myUrl) {
    if (origin == 'Storage') {
      return Image.network(myUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.fill, width: double.infinity,);
    }

    if (origin == 'Phone') {
      return Image.file(File(myUrl),
        fit: BoxFit.fill, width: double.infinity,);
    }
    return containerContentCard;
  }
```

```
 getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(String fileName) {

    switch (extensionFile){

      case 'pdf':
        return Image.asset('assets/images/logo_pdf.png',
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          width: double.infinity,);

      break;

      case 'jpeg':

          return containerContentCard(source,_fileName);

        break;

      case 'aac':

          return Image.asset('assets/images/logo_pdf.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            width: double.infinity,);

        break;
    }
  }
```

```
 child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [

                    getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(
                    newFilesAdded[index]),

                    /*SizedBox(
                        height: 113, width: 113,
                        child: getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(
                            newFilesAdded[index])),*/
```

[image]

Comment: add the code for `containerContentCard`

Comment: I have added the missing part. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

`containerContentCard` method is returning `return containerContentCard` in the end, that's the issue. Remove that return statement or return some empty widget from there such as `return SizedBox();`.

```dart
Widget containerContentCard(String origin, myUrl) {
  // if block 1
  // if block 2
  
  return SizedBox();
}
```

Also in `getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay`, add an empty widget return statement.

```dart
Widget getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(String fileName) {
  // switch block

  return SizedBox();
}
```

Comment: I have tried but now I am getting an other error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: check now... updated my answer.

Comment: I still have the same error Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: add return type of methods as `Widget`.

Comment: done, but I still have the same error.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. On the left of the file name, I want to display a SizedBox 113 x 113 where I display a preview of the jpg selected.

Comment: on which line you're getting `'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'`?

Comment: on this one    getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(
                    newFilesAdded[index]),

Comment: did you add return statement at the end of `getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay` and also added the return type?

Comment: Yes. return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
        height: 113, width: 113,);

Comment: I think we're missing something. Could you please update the question code with the changes? Also try using `??` opeartor like: `getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(newFilesAdded[index]) ?? Container()`

Comment: add bang operator for `newFilesAdded` if required.

Comment: what is bang operator please?

Comment: getFileExtensionToDetermineWitchImageToDisplay(
                    newFilesAdded[index])??Container(), the text Container is in grey like when I am adding a comment //